# display the documentlibrary folders in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

i'm getting the documentlibrary folders. but i don't know how to display the geeting folders in a MainPage.Xaml (design page).

here is my code:

```
var folders = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();
```

if anyone guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you've a ListView to show all the folders. And on click of a button, you want to show list of folders in DocumentsLibrary. For this, use following XAML:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <ListView x:Name="FolderList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="216,328,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="830">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Now, in code behind write following code:

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folders = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();
        var data = folders.ToList<Windows.Storage.StorageFolder>();
        FolderList.ItemsSource = data;

    }
```

This will show you all the folders within the DocumentsLibrary in ListView.
Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ListView or GridView or ListBox in XAML (depending on what you want to do with it) and bind it to the folders list. Then you need an ItemTemplate to specify what you want displayed e.g. folder name, path, size etc